# seekp not seeking to proper location?

Tags: c++, fstream

I have the following code:

```
  file.open(fileName, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
   // many lines later
  file.seekp(fooAddr, ios::beg);
  printf("foo_addr: %d\n", foo_addr);
  file.write((char*)fooStruct, sizeof(FooStruct));
```

I know that `fooAddr` is 128 due to the `printf`.
Yet, for some reason, when I open the target file in my hex editor, the first byte is written at location 80.

[image]

Is this possible? Or is there some bug I am overlooking in my program?

I guess, for context, all my file operations are wrapped in a macro that checks if `file.goodbit` is not 0 (truthy), and if so -- the program immediately exits after printing an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hex editor is displaying file offsets in hexadecimal format, not in decimal.

Decimal 128 is hex 0x80.